# Capture subset or match result with Regex

Tags: java, regex

I have this String

```
null,"category":"Cooking \u0026 Baking Needs","nonInteraction":true}
```

And this regex: `\"category\":\"([^"]*)\"`

Which matches this `"category":"Cooking \u0026 Baking Needs"`

However, I only need to capture the `Cooking \u0026 Baking Needs` (without the quotes)

What is missing in my regex?

Comment: Nothing is missing in the regex, but in how you're using it, but you didn't share that code, so you can't tell you exactly what you did wrong. Well, we can guess that you called `group()` instead of `group(1)`.

Comment: No I am just using https://regexr.com/ for testing now

Comment: That looks like JSON, so perhaps you should use a JSON parser instead, because that regex may fail on certain values.

Comment: If you're using regexr.com, and don't have any Java code, why are you asking a Java question? Write Java code to test your Java regex. regexr.com doesn't even support Java's flavor of regex anyway.

Comment: Yes its a JSON but in a stream of text which is a pre-rendered html actually...

Comment: Use http://regex101.com instead of http://regexr.com. It actually shows you the capture group you're after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this `(?<=\"category\":\")([^"]*)(?=\")`

[Online demo](https://regex101.com/r/1iajQe/1)